# Why is PyTorch's Dataloader is not inerrable?

Tags: python, deep-learning, logistic-regression, pytorch

I am working on MNIST dataset for an assignment and it seems to be I am stuck at some point for long. I have wrote my code for LogisticRegression and when I try to train the model it is not working as expected but instead it throws an error which says:

```
Input tensor should be a torch tensor. Got <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>.
```

Dataloader:

```
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

My Code:

```
class LogisticRegression(torch.nn.Module):

def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
    super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
    self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)
    

def forward(self, x):
    x = x.reshape(-1, 784)
    outputs = self.linear(x)
    return outputs
```

Train the model:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
   for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
   optimizer.zero_grad()

   y_pred = model(images)

   loss = criterion(y_pred, labels)

   loss.backward()
    
   optimizer.step()
```

Where am I going wrong with the code?

Edit:

I changed in the code at:

```
mnist_rest = datasets.MNIST(data_dir, download=True, train=True, transform=transforms.Normalize((mean,), (std,)))
```

So instead of that piece I have replaced with:

```
mnist_rest = datasets.MNIST(data_dir, download=True, train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
```

So my question is now can we achieve the inerrable object with `transforms.Normalize`method?

Comment: So you want to normalize your image and then convert it to a tensor?

Comment: @DevashishPrasad Yes but its solved now. I misunderstood and I have used `transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((mean,), (std,))])` and it works just fine. Thanks anyway for taking interest.